# Inline buttons in Windows Forms Possible?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm trying to make a row of an unknown(at design time) number of buttons that behave like an inline element in HTML. That is, instead of overflowing their container, they move a line down like text in a text box would. I know I could write something that positions them manually within a panel, but does Windows Forms offer something like this already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like a [FlowLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) would suit your needs.

You can control the flow direction (which is defaulted to L-R) and any controls that would extend past the panel should wrap down to the next line.

Example screenshot from [dotnetperls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/flowlayoutpanel):
[image: FlowLayoutPanel with controls wrapping to the next line]

Comment: A flowlayout will not work if the button can fit in the same line.

Comment: in addition [here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxfYFAw0JDs) demonstrating exactly what OP has asked for using the FlowLayoutPanel

Comment: @CodingYoshi - If the button can fit on the same line, how is that not doing what OP wants? If it fits on the same line it wouldn't be overflowing the container. Or am I misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: @DangerZone nevermind, your answer is good. I misread the question. It seems the user wants to fill the row and then move onto the next row.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492143.aspx). Every time you need to add a new button, add a new row to the panel and add the button to the row.

At design time set the height of the row to whatever you want (it aslo has AutoSize option). You need one column in the panel if you want each button on a separate line. But the option of having extra columns is there as well.